# How to make a popup menu appear in onCreate?

Tags: android, menu, dialog

I have an options menu that is called by clicking on the menu-button, BUT I want an options menu that is called right when the app starts.
it's a LANGUAGE CHOICE setting.

I searched a lot, but I only find how to make it appear `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`

Comment: You can open your optionsmenu any time with the openOptionsMenu() function, if thats what you want.

Comment: i thought this opens the same like the Android's menu-button?

Comment: @BigX_Jazz have a look on my edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am certain you are looking for how to open a menu in a programmatic way,

The following link has a pretty good example,

http://kahdev.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/progamatically-open-and-close-an-activitys-option-menu/

You can get your task done by doing some slight modifications of that example tutorial.

**EDIT**

for custom menu, you need to create your own with xml or java. But XML is preferred.

example menu from [developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
          android:title="@string/new_game"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
          android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

then you need to inflate the menu resource in-order to use within the activity

example from [developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu)

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT**

Then you can simply do with alert dialog with `setSingleChoiceItems();`

The [developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog) site has enough examples for each dialog type.

For example alert dialog

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        // This is the place where you need to execute the logic            
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

But you need to call `alert.show();` to display the dialog, for instance you can call within the `onResume()` method

Comment: but by thi examplethe menu will only appear if abutton is clicked, right?

Comment: @BigX_Jazz then call the method within activitie's `onResume();`

Comment: but my optionsmenu that appears with the menu clicked is another, than the one i want to be shown at startup

Comment: If you want to modify the options menu dynamically at runtime, override `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` instead.

Comment: i dont want to modify it, i have a optionsmenu that is called by the menu-button and everything is fine with that. BUT i want ANOTHER options menu that is only called once when the app is starting.

Comment: @BigX_Jazz ok, then you are looking for a custom dialog which behaves like a menu but not actually an options menu or context menu. isn't it? Your question is misleading.

Comment: Sorry for that. i reforumulated my question in the first post

Answer (score 0):

OnCreate runs always your Activity is created, if you create a AlertDialog and call show() at this moment, it will show only after your activty completed it's initalization (after onResume()), before it, there is nothing at screen.

Would you pleas explain what are you expact to happen?

Comment: I want a menu to popup at the startup of my app. This menu should contain two items. One can be selected.Thats all

Comment: AlertDialog doesn't worked? (You can set its view and call show() the way you want).

Comment: Can set the view byan existing xml?

Comment: Sure, but you will need to inflate: 
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflater.inflate(id, null);